# Calling Card Integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I need to develop an application to integrate calling card functionality. The application will have an access number, a country code and a pin number setting.

When a user wants to make a call the system should dial the access number and then after a time interval it should dial the country code and finally pin number followed by the actual telephone number.

How would one implement this?

Comment: This isn't a question, it's asking for code...

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking code, Whether it is doable or not. Which is the right way to do it?

Comment: You've asked 7 questions and accepted none. As stated in the FAQ "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)"

Comment: I do understand, I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might work, haven't tried it. Won't work in simulator. Real answer s/b close

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"te1://12125551212,,,%@,,,%@", numLang, numPin];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[app openURL:url];
```

Comma are pauses.

Comment: Thanks Jordan,You specified here 3 comma for pauses.How long it will be pause. If i want to pauses it for specific time interval, How many comma i want to use? Please help me?